# Active-X vs Ajax Internet client-server communication

Tags: ajax, activex, client-server, polling

I have to use scanner on Internet site web page. As far as I know not Flash nor Silverlight is capable to communicate with such hardware nowadays. It looks like there is no alternative to Active-X at present for such operation (correct me if I'm wrong).

After image is scanned I have to send it to server via HTTPS and wait for processing result.

I have some alternatives here:

- Start ajax polling with regular interval
- Put polling functionality straight into active-x component

What approach would you personally preffer?

Is it possible to establish event mechanism for Active-X approach (when server pushes result back to a web-page?). Will events work for javascript/ajax approach?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the client scan and upload a file. That's how it's done these days. Scanning software is a part of OS - at least, in Windows and MacOS it is.

With an ActiveX object, it will become a support nightmare. Also, think of all the Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Non-Windows users out there.

Also, I vaguely recall scanner support will be added in HTML5.

Comment: Thank you, @Seva. It's a customer requirement to use web browser for such operation - I can't change that.

Comment: If the customer agrees to be bound to IE on Windows, so be it. That said, the less functionality in ActiveX, the better. Web bits are easier to debug and replace.